# Merge objects based on a list of dicts which is stored in a nested field

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.9.x - I have a problem where I'd like to merge a list of dicts in an optimal way. However, these aren't simple dicts - there is an ID which is a simple numeric ID; and a list of dicts called "codes" - which is where the list of dicts to merge from are stored.

An example of raw data is below:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1234",
    "codes" : [
      {
        "provider" : "provider1",
        "id" : "1234",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider2",
        "id" : "AA0001",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider3",
        "id" : "tt00001",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider4",
        "id" : "0000-0000-27E0-0000-9-0000-0000-A",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id" : "12345",
    "codes" : [
      {
        "provider" : "provider1",
        "id" : "2345",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider3",
        "id" : "tt00001",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider4",
        "id" : "0000-0000-27E0-0000-9-0000-0000-A",
      }
      {
        "provider" : "provider5",
        "id" : "F0046872",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "123456",
    "codes": [
        {
            "id": "0000", 
            "provider": "provider6"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

In the above example, we can see there are two common dicts in the "codes" list for two objects (with IDs: "1234" and "12345"):

```
      {
        "provider" : "provider3",
        "id" : "tt00001",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider4",
        "id" : "0000-0000-27E0-0000-9-0000-0000-A",
      }
```

As long as there is one common provider and id combination - we should trigger a merge. Hence objects with IDs 1234 and 12345 should be merged.

However, the desired output would preserve all the objects with all IDs, i.e.,:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1234",
    "codes" : [
      {
        "provider" : "provider1",
        "id" : "1234",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider2",
        "id" : "AA0001",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider3",
        "id" : "tt00001",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider4",
        "id" : "0000-0000-27E0-0000-9-0000-0000-A",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider5",
        "id" : "F0046872",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id" : "12345",
    "codes" : [
      {
        "provider" : "provider1",
        "id" : "2345",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider3",
        "id" : "tt00001",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider5",
        "id" : "F0046872",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider2",
        "id" : "AA0001",
      },
      {
        "provider" : "provider4",
        "id" : "0000-0000-27E0-0000-9-0000-0000-A",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "123456",
    "codes": [
        {
            "id": "0000", 
            "provider": "provider6"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Some code so far where:

- The codes_file has the same data as shown in the raw data above
- The Codes class the raw_data is read into is simply a python dataclass

```
    def test_codes_extractor_flattener(self, codes_extractor: CodesExtractor):
        codes_file = os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
            "data/codes_cache_flatten.txt",
        )
        codes_cache = []
        with open(codes_file, "r") as in_file:
            data = ast.literal_eval(in_file.read())
            for raw_data in data:
                for code in raw_data["codes"]:
                    for raw_data_ in data:
                        for code_ in raw_data_["codes"]:
                            if code_["provider"] == code["provider"] and \
                                    code_["id"] == code["id"]:
                                self.merge(raw_data, raw_data_)
                                continue
                        continue
                codes_cache.append(Codes(**raw_data))
        assert len(codes_cache) == 2
        for codes in codes_cache:
            assert len(codes.codes) == 6

    def merge(self, code_1, code_2):
        code_2_codes = code_2["codes"]
        for code_ in code_1["codes"]:
            if code_ not in code_2_codes:
                code_2_codes.append(code_)
```

Note:

- The order of the provider fields does not matter (as shown by the second entry in the desired output
- The "id" field outside the "codes" list must be preserved.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have written so far to try to solve this problem?

Comment: Code added @C_Z_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to merge all `codes` in the list if they have common providers or any two of them. Here's a way to merge all of them. If it's any two of them, you can still probably use `itertools` to iterate by choice. I'd try to work on a solution for that case, but it's lunchtime for me :D

```py
from pprint import pprint
import typing as ty


class Data(ty.TypedDict):
    id: str
    codes: ty.List[ty.Dict[str, str]]


data: ty.List[Data] = [
    ... # your initial raw data
]

# merge all the codes
merged_codes = set()
id_codes: Data
for id_codes in data:
    for code in id_codes["codes"]:
        merged_codes.add(frozenset(code.items()))

len_all_codes = sum(len(id_codes["codes"]) for id_codes in data)

if len(merged_codes) < len_all_codes:  # so some got merged
    # update all codes to only have the merged providers
    for id_codes in data:
        id_codes["codes"] = [dict(obj) for obj in merged_codes]

pprint(data)
```

Prints

```
$ python3 tmp.py
[{'codes': [{'id': '2345', 'provider': 'provider1'},
            {'id': 'F0046872', 'provider': 'provider5'},
            {'id': '1234', 'provider': 'provider1'},
            {'id': 'AA0001', 'provider': 'provider2'},
            {'id': 'tt00001', 'provider': 'provider3'},
            {'id': '0000-0000-27E0-0000-9-0000-0000-A',
             'provider': 'provider4'}],
  'id': '1234'},
 {'codes': [{'id': '2345', 'provider': 'provider1'},
            {'id': 'F0046872', 'provider': 'provider5'},
            {'id': '1234', 'provider': 'provider1'},
            {'id': 'AA0001', 'provider': 'provider2'},
            {'id': 'tt00001', 'provider': 'provider3'},
            {'id': '0000-0000-27E0-0000-9-0000-0000-A',
             'provider': 'provider4'}],
  'id': '12345'}]
```

Comment: Hi Ben!

I appreciate the answer. However, this would merge all codes and would ignore the condition which should trigger the merge in the question:
`As long as there is one common provider and id combination - we should trigger a merge.`

There could be an id_code which has no common "id" and "provider" and so should not be merged but preserved, e.g.,

`{"id": "123456", "codes": [{"id": "0000", "provider": "provider6"}]}`

This should not be merged but preserved in the list of all id_codes

Comment: @vinayman, could you add this to your example data?